# cual es la necesidad de castear una clase hija a una padre?

Tags: java, poo

buenos dias solo una pregunta ya que no me queda muy clara la idea de castear un objeto de la clase hija a una clase padre (ya que practicamente la hija puede acceder a las propiedades y metodos del padre) 
tengo mi clase padre:

```
package interfacesypolimorfismo;

    import java.sql.Time;

    public  class cinegrafia {

    protected int sdx;

    public int TiempoDemora;
    public String nombre_pelicula;

    public cinegrafia(int TiempoDemora, String nombre_pelicula) {
    this.TiempoDemora = TiempoDemora;
    this.nombre_pelicula = nombre_pelicula;
  }

  public void cualquiercosa(){

  }




  protected void esProtected(){

 }    

 }
```

tambien tengo la hija:

```
   public class PeliculaDocumental extends cinegrafia{

   public String TipoDeDocumental;

    public PeliculaDocumental(String TipoDeDocumental,int 
    TiempoDemora,String 
    nombre_pelicula) {
    super(TiempoDemora, nombre_pelicula);
    this.TipoDeDocumental = TipoDeDocumental;
  }  

 }
```

y hago el casteo:

```
     PeliculaDocumental xd = new PeliculaDocumental("asd", 45, "asd");

    cinegrafia xsd = (cinegrafia) xd;
```

pero no le hallo la necesidad ahi ya que el objeto xd puede acceder a todas las cosas de cinegrafia. muchas gracias por su aclaracion o ayuda :).

Comment: ¿De dónde sacas la idea de que es *necesario* hacer el casting? En todo caso la explicación es al revés, como estás seguro de que una instancia de `PeliculaDocumental` es también una instancia de `cinegrafía` (relación *es-un*), puedes estar seguro de que la instancia `xd` cumple el "contrato" de `cinegrafia`

Comment: Aparte, los nombres de clases e interfaces deberían empezar por mayúsculas (no es que afecte a tu pregunta, pero los estándares suelen ser útiles).

Comment: Esta línea de código, te la inventas innecesariamente: `cinegrafia xsd = (cinegrafia) xd;` ... la misma no sirve absolutamente **para nada**. Si `PeliculaDocumental` extiende de `Cinegrafria`, nada más crea la instancia así: `PeliculaDocumental xd = new PeliculaDocumental("asd", 45, "asd");` y luego podrás hacer cosas como estas sin más: `xd.cualquierCosa();` ¿A qué viene que te compliques la vida inventando cosas que no son? Convendría que leas sobre [herencia en Java](https://jarroba.com/herencia-en-la-programacion-orientada-a-objetos-ejemplo-en-java/) viendo cómo funciona.

Comment: Imagínate que tienes otra clase hija con diferentes parámetros. Cada clase tiene sus parámetros distintos y los de padre en común.

Ahora imagínate que tenemos un método en otra clase distinta (ni padre ni hijas) y queremos que pueda procesar todos (padre e hijas). En vez de implementar el método varias veces recibiendo cada una de las hijas, lo dejas recibiendo el padre que valdrá que reciba una hija o la otra.